# Getting Vendor ID/Product through WndProc

Tags: c#, serial-port, windows-messages

In C#, I write code to detect arrival/removal of device information from Serial Port.

```
private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219;
            // System detects a new device
            const int DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000;
            // The device has been succesfully removed from the system
            const int DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004;

            if (msg == WM_DEVICECHANGE)
            {
                switch (wParam.ToInt32())
                {
                    case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
                        MessageBox.Show("New device added");
                        break;
                    case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:
                        MessageBox.Show("An device has been removed from system");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
```

I searched on Google and I founded this article.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60579/A-USB-Library-to-Detect-USB-Devices

It gives me exactly the code I need to write. But I have to provide to it a PID and VID.

So that, I need to combine my code with above code to make an program that automatically show information about arrival/removal of a device.

My problems is: From the WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled), how to extract the device's VID and PID?.

Comment: Personally I would use WMI events for this, but even there there is no separate VID and PID fields: I ended up matching in the `deviceId` string of the `Win32_PnpEntity` object; this device in question having a device id "USB\VID_0483&PID_A07A\6&1AB5E341&0&6". (When I looked through all the devices properties in device manager I found nothing better.)